# MySQL countdown procedure

Tags: mysql, datetime, stored-procedures

Is it possible to create some kind of MySQL function/procedure/routine/event/whatever that compares the server datetime with a table record field datetime and starts counting and updating a same record "seconds" field every second passes by?

Being more specific.
I have a table record with a field datetime for example with this data:

06-03-2015 17:15 (below minutes not important)

I want MySQL to check the server time with this field datetime and when it reaches that date, starts updating another field in the same record every second, like a countdown. All this automatically through some kind of procedure.

Is it possible? And if it is, can someone give some guidelines or point me in the right direction?

Comment: I guess you could do this with the MySQL Event Scheduler.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html

Comment: Thanks @Barmar and @Matze! I'm really new at this and sometimes a "push" is all we need. By the way, another "push" will be welcomed. I'm thinking of do it by creating 2 events. First one will check dates every minute and when matched, starts 2nd event that will update data every second. What do you think?